# MIPS User Input Int array finding only first array element

Tags: assembly, mips

So I have a program in MIPS assembly for class, I am meant to have the user create an array of a given size and then output the greatest element.  However, I cannot access anything except the first array element when trying to output.  I've been debugging for a few hours now and I can't seem to find the problem. My code is below:

```
.

data
array: .space 40
size: .asciiz "Enter the size of the array (0 to 10): "
get: .asciiz "\nEnter an integer: "
error: .asciiz "\n!!!Invalid! Please input a size between 0 and 10: "
answer: .asciiz "\nThe largest element is: "

.text
main:
    #get the size
    li $t2, 10
    li $v0, 4
        la $a0, size
        syscall
        #get a size int, put in $t0
    li $v0, 5
        syscall
        move $t0, $v0
        slt $t3, $t2, $t0
    #$t3 equals zero if they are not equal
    slt $t3, $t2, $t0
    getsize: beq $t3, $zero, store
        li $v0, 4
            la $a0, error
            syscall
        li $v0, 5
            syscall
            move $t0, $v0
            slt $t3, $t2, $t0
        j getsize

        store:  
            #initialize a loop counter
            li $t1, 0
            #initialize a register with the address of array
            la $s1, array
            #loop method, with beq
            initialize: beq $t1, $t0, read
                #print the get integer message
                li $v0, 4
                la $a0, get
                syscall
                #get the input
                li $v0, 5
                syscall
                move $t4, $v0

                #move the input to register $t4
                #sw $t4, 0($s1)
                sw $t4, 0($s1)
                addi $s1, $s1, 4
                #store word in the array
                #increment the loop's counter
                addi $t1, $t1, 1
                j initialize

        read: #initialize array address
            la  $s0, array
            #array counter
            li $t1, 0
            #largest found
            lw $t2, 0($s0)
            addi $s0, $s0, 4
            find: beq $t1, $t0, printResult
                #load the value of the array element
                lw $t4, ($s0)
                #increment the array
                addi $s0, $s0, 4
                #set less than to judge the current greatest against the new element
                #1 if the new element is less than the old element
                #0 if the new element is >= the old element 
                slt $t3, $t4, $t2
                #if the new one is less than, we jump back to the top
                bne $t3, $zero, find
                #otherwise, we move make the new one the greatest and increment $t1
                move $t4, $t2
                addi $t1, $t1, 1
                #jump to the top of the loop
                j find

        printResult:
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, answer
            syscall

            li $v0, 1
            move $a0, $t2
        syscall

    #end program
    end:li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Comment: _"I cannot access anything except the first array element"_ It's not clear exactly what you mean by "cannot access". But what you should do is set a breakpoint at the place in the code where you're trying to access/use the array elements, and single-step from there, paying attention to the contents of all relevant registers as you move along.

Comment: From a 10sec read of source, you are doing `s1/s0 = array address`, and then access elements as `0(s1/s0)` and increment those addresses by 4 (byte size of element) = everything looks OK, so either you damage the s1/s0 content inside loop, or something else (loop ends after first iteration?), or it works and does something different what you expected, but as far as accessing array is involved, the 10sec check is OK, describe better what happens.

Comment: Yeah sorry! I should've been more specific.  So say I enter 3 for the size, and then 1, 5, and 3.  What happens is that in the find loop, the $t2 address gets changed to have a value of 1, and remains unchanged even traversing the second and third indices of the array. Then this 1 value gets returned. @Ped7g

Comment: So, when you are in debugger, and you go through the `find` loop, and `t2 = 1` and `t4 = 5`, the `slt + bne` does the correct thing I guess, and then what happens after `move $t4, $t2`? I wonder how did you miss that in debugging, try to search in your ways, how that happened, and what you can change to improve and catch such things, it's like "obvious", that when you expect the current max to update to 5, something is wrong, when it stays 1. Also you don't update `t1` count in find-loop properly, so the loop may be infinite for input like `2, 1`, or at least reach far beyond end of array.

Comment: Actually according to your comment you update `$t1` exactly as you planned, but it doesn't make sense to me, you may want to think for a short while about your algorithm, and maybe even do a dry-run on paper, also to validate you don't get +1 beyond end, as you already pick first value as possible max, and then you start loop on second value, but count from zero. (I didn't check if `t0` contains human count like "2" for two elements, or "1" (would be weird)). - and that's what you should do in debugger, make note on paper what kind of values you expect in regs for some input, and verify *ALL*.

Answer (score 0):

You can access all elements of the array, you are actually accessing even more values, beyond the end of your array, so access is not your real problem.

Your problem is only the first value is being printed as result instead of largest value.

That happens because you don't store the larger value anywhere when you find one, so your `t2` register will keep the first-element value until the loop eventually ends by accident (due to wrong `t1` loop counter logic), and then you print out that first element as result.

The largest value update needs just to switch arguments of `move $t4, $t2`, but you should redesign also the loop counter logic, and make sure you don't reach for element after array (as you are skipping first array element, so the loop should run only over size-1 elements, or you can initialize t1=1 to get that size-1 iterations, once you fix incrementing logic of it).